# eclipse does not find sound path

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, jar, path

In this code

```
in = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/sonidos/inicio.wav").toString());
```

Eclipse said that:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\OcioZ\Dropbox\Iker-Diego\JavaMusicianClient\bin\sonidos\inicio.wav (The file name, dir. name or vol. label name are not correct)
```

but sound file exists. I am writting "getClass().getResource("...").toString()" to jar file recognized then.

If I only write relative path:

```
 in = new FileInputStream("/sonidos/inicio.wav");
```

the sound play correctly in Eclipse but then in jar file does not sound.

Any ideas??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/sonidos/inicio.wav"
```

is an absolute path.  Try using a relative path:

```
in = new FileInputStream("./sonidos/inicio.wav");
```

or

```
in = new FileInputStream("sonidos/inicio.wav");
```

You could also try using `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource()`.